# JPA2 select list from entity

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a JPA mapping with a oneToMany, now I want to select this collection with a CriteriaQuery, just like

```
query.select(Root_.collection).where(cb.equal(root.id, id))
List<ResultObject> results = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

I can't imagine this isn't possible at all... Because from a repository it is possible too...

The use case for this is to put the result of several queries in a DTO.

Thnx!

Comment: What is the result of running that code snippet? First thing that comes to mind is the `FetchType`. Did you set the fetchtype for the OneToMany collection to `Eager`?

Comment: It's a lazy fetch, as I don't want to load all the collection, when we don't need them

Answer (score 0):

> The use of collections in **select clause** is not allowed and so this
>   **query.select(Root_.collection)** does not work in Criteria API.

You can do this, though not recommended approach (http://www.kumaranuj.com/2013/07/jpa-2-fetch-joins-and-whether-we-should.html):

```
    root.fetch(Root_.collection);
    query.select(root).distinct(true).where(cb.equal(root.get("id"), id));
```

Then from the above, depending on the number of distinct Root rows returned, you can now access the collection for oneToMany relationship in the root as below:

```
    final Root result = em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult(); //Since we are getting results using primary key and distinct, we then use getSingleResult
    final Collection rootCollection = result.getCollection();
```

Key points here are in the use of **root.fetch(Root_.collection)** and **select(root).distinct(true)**.